# how to load google/flan-t5-xl in 8 bit in GPU RAM (Colab)

Tags: pytorch, google-colaboratory, huggingface-transformers

I'm trying to figure out how to load quantized models in GPU RAM.

Use case: `google/flan-t5-xl` is large, and does not load by default in regular Colab.

However if I load it directly to cuda, using `torch.set_default_tensor_type(torch.cuda.FloatTensor)` it fits (just barely).

I.e. this works:

```
torch.set_default_tensor_type(torch.cuda.FloatTensor)
model = T5ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained('google/flan-t5-xl')
```

But since it's near edge and slow, I want to try loading it in 8-bit.

```py
model = T5ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained('google/flan-t5-xl', 
                                                       device_map='auto', 
                                                       load_in_8bit=True)
```

But this doesn't work.  I'm guessing the device_map='auto' overrides 'send to cuda' instructions.  I tried making a custom device_map, and it just crushed even faster.

Is there a way to load the `load_in_8bit` model versions to CUDA?

Comment: Have you installed the `bitsandbytes` package compiled for your CUDA version as stated by the [documentation](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/model#transformers.PreTrainedModel.from_pretrained.load_in_8bit)?

Comment: @cronoik Thanks for pointing it out.  Colab's CUDA version is 12.0.  I tried the command in the doc, and it can't find that version. Based on  https://github.com/TimDettmers/bitsandbytes version 12 should be supported with basic `pip install bitsandbytes` by default. I can't figure out if there a way to specify compiling for exact CUDA on colab

Comment: @cronoik actually I checked `!nvcc --version` and it says CUDA-11.8 .  I then checked `!python -m bitsandbytes` to see what CUDA was setup and it says `CUDA SETUP: Detected CUDA version 118`.  There are no bugs reported at setup, so I think the compatibility isn't the issue